# Lucene boost result on other field

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Licene.net.

I have docs in index with 2 fields: *text* and *tag*.

I need query that will search for some value in *text* field and after that boost result by *tag* field.

In other word, I select docs using text field and sort them by tag field (if any matches in tag field, raise that doc up in search result).

**How can I build that query?**

Comment: Do you mean you want a higher score for documents containing some special tag over those which don't?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a higher score for documents which have some tag over those which don't, you can add this as an optional `SHOULD` clause in your query.

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
bq.add(/* your text query */, Occur.MUST);
bq.add(new TermQuery(new Term("Key", key)), Occur.SHOULD);
```

Results which satisfy SHOULD clauses will have higher score.

You can also `setBoost()` on the second query, to make it affect the score more than the first one.